# Outside Frost Proof Spigot sprays water

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have a frost proof outside spigot. When I hook the hose to it, as much water comes out near the front of the spigot (not the top) as comes out of the end of the hose. What is wrong with it? Do I need to call a plumber and have the whole thing replaced?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this only when you turn the spigot on? Could you post a picture (or a URL of a picture)?

Comment: Does the hose have a rubber washer in it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it has a vacuum-breaker, and the vacuum-breaker valve/disc is stuck or failed.

Or, depending on what you mean for the leak location, the packing on the valve stem is loose or needs to be replaced.